# Modelagem de banco de dados de um sistema de notas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso criar um banco de dados para um sistema de notas, porém sou péssimo com modelagem de dados. Fiz a modelagem mas não sei se está correta. Os campos ainda não são definitivos, só quero saber se os relacionamentos estão corretos.

A especificação do problema é:

No cadastro de alunos devem ser informados os dados: nome, data de
nascimento, sexo, endereço, cidade, Estado, CPF, RG, telefone e CR. Para
informar as notas é preciso ter os dados do curso e das disciplinas. Cada curso
tem nome e um código, e pode oferecer diversas disciplinas. Para cada
disciplina deve ser informado o código, o nome e a ementa. A cada período,
uma disciplina pode ter várias turmas associada a ela. Vale lembrar que uma
turma pertence exclusivamente a uma única disciplina. Uma turma pode ter
diversos alunos matriculados e tem um número máximo de alunos. Um aluno
pode estar matriculado em várias turmas. Para cada turma é necessário
informar as notas da avaliação 1, da avaliação 2 e a média final dos alunos que
a compõem. Uma turma pode ter mais de um professor, assim como um
professor pode lecionar em mais de uma turma. Alguns dados de professor
importantes, nesse contexto, são: matricula, nome, área de formação, última
titulação e regime de contratação. A partir dessas informações, crie as tabelas,
considere as chaves primárias e estrangeiras e insira informações nas tabelas.

Utilizei o StarUML

[image: DER do modelo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder já que o requisito está bem claro. Ele não é um bom requisito para o mundo real, mas o objetivo deve ser fazer o modelo de acordo com o enunciado.

Quando for fazer algo tente organizar a informação da melhor forma para entender melhor.

> No cadastro de alunos devem ser informados os dados: nome, data de nascimento, sexo, endereço, cidade, Estado, CPF, RG, telefone e CR.

Então temos aí uma tabela definida e as colunas que deve ter. Note que é apenas uma tabela, seu modelo criou duas tabelas, e portanto relacionamentos desnecessários para este modelo, é muito simples, crie apenas uma tabela, não tem porque quebrar em algo que o requisito não pede. A não ser que tenha um requisito que peça para fazer um modelo melhorado para o uso no mundo real, aí teria muita coisa errada nesse modelo e depende da avaliação de cada um, nem parta para isso sem muita experiência ou se o objetivo for fazer para o professor fazer a crítica e poder ver onde errou, aí o erro seria mais importante que entregar certo.

> Para informar as notas é preciso ter os dados do curso e das disciplinas.

Tem 3 tabelas definidas aí, uma delas quase implicitamente.

> Cada curso tem nome e um código, e pode oferecer diversas disciplinas.

Aqui detalha uma delas e diz que o relacionamento é de "um para muitos", como você o fez.

> Para cada disciplina deve ser informado o código, o nome e a ementa.

Feito perfeitamente.

> A cada período, uma disciplina pode ter várias turmas associada a ela.

Aqui o requisito fica confuso. Que período é este? Em nenhum momento se fala mais dele, então já complicou resolver isso de forma adequada. Talvez o período se confunda com turma, por isso não fala mais nele.

Mas pelo menos ajuda entender o relacionamento de duas novas tabelas, `turma` e `disciplina`. Também há uma falha que não diz nada sobre a turma, então vou considerar que só o código é adequado, pelo menos dá para argumentar a favor dessa decisão.

> Vale lembrar que uma turma pertence exclusivamente a uma única disciplina.

Aqui deixa claro que essas duas tabelas tem um relacionamento "um para muitos", como fez.

> Uma turma pode ter diversos alunos matriculados e tem um número máximo de alunos. Um aluno pode estar matriculado em várias turmas.

Aqui mostra que estas duas tabelas possuem relacionamento "muitos para muitos", e fez corretamente. Alguns diagramas permitem dizer quantos podem ser muitos, se o requisito fala sobre isto então deveria usar um diagrama que demonstre isso, algo como `1:N`.

Na verdade aqui o enunciado se mostra ruim, se ele quer esse nível de detalhamento deveria dar mais informações. Em nenhum lugar indica o que pode ser relacionamento nulo, ou seja, pode ser `0..1:N` ou só pode ser `1:N`. O mesmo vale para os outros relacionamentos, então neste caso vou considerar que 0 nunca pode ocorrer, acho que é um boa inferência, mas não dá pra cravar por deficiência do requisito neste ponto.

> Para cada turma é necessário informar as notas da avaliação 1, da avaliação 2 e a média final dos alunos que a compõem.

Aqui modela uma das tabelas em detalhe, nada difícil e fez corretamente. E parece ser a tabela central. Não está errado fazer diferente, mas é comum colocá-la no centro e as demais "orbitar" em torno dela para visualização ficar mais clara. E aqui tem o erro mais grave, onde está a tabela mais importante do modelo? E aí tem um complicador porque cada nota se relaciona com uma disciplina e aluno ao mesmo tempo. Você não pode relacionar cada nota diretamente com os dois ao mesmo tempo, então precisa de uma tabela auxiliar para fazer a amarração das duas tabelas. Não posso afirmar para o exercício, mas é assim que se costuma resolver isso. Pode ser uma falha do enunciado, mas pode ser proposital para ser o ponto principal que teria que pensar. Então isso vou deixar para melhorar. Tem [perguntas sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=amarra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20tabela).

> Uma turma pode ter mais de um professor, assim como um professor pode lecionar em mais de uma turma.

Fala de uma nova tabela e como ela se relaciona com a já citada `turma`, sendo "muitos para muitos", como fez corretamente.

> Alguns dados de professor importantes, nesse contexto, são: matricula, nome, área de formação, última titulação e regime de contratação.

Aqui detalha uma das tabelas e fez corretamente, não tem segredo.

> A partir dessas informações, crie as tabelas, considere as chaves primárias e estrangeiras e insira informações nas tabelas

Eu gostaria de um modelo mais detalhado com tipagem e outras informações de cada coluna. Isto é parte fundamental para a modelagem. Mas não posso dizer se o exercício obriga isto, então se não obriga ele está certo, mas é um modelo incompleto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. A modelagem desse banco é um exercício passado em uma aula, então acho que o professor não detalhou tanto. Só uma outra pergunta já que criar um tópico sobre fugiria do objetivo do site. Um programador precisa saber modelar banco de dados ou isso é trabalho do DBA, Arquiteto etc?

Comment: A minha experiência é que modelar dados é o conhecimento fundamental de todo desenvolvedor, porque na verdade modelar dados nada tem a ver com banco de dados. Por acaso banco de dado é um dos lugares onde isso está sendo usado. Modelar dados é o que se faz o tempo todo em programação, e se as pessoas pensassem mais nisso teriam código bem melhores. Especialmente o fanatismo que as pessoas tem por OOP, elas nem percebem que a única coisa que conta nisso é modelar o dado, OOP é só uma técnica muito simples de fazer isso, e complexa de fazer certo porque modelar é difícil pra caramba.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi qual a sua dúvida. Se for para análisar os relacionamentos apenas, eu diria que está em um bom caminho, apenas alteraria a tabela de endereços, destrincharia ela em mais duas e moveria alguns dados para a tabela de alunos. No caso uma tabela contendo apenas os estados, outra com as cidades e rua e número na tabela de usuários, bem como telefone, visto que não será um dado compartilhado entre muitos ou nenhum usuário.

Comment: E por que ele faria isto se o enunciado não pede para fazer assim?

Comment: Ele pediu para validar os relacionametos, o enunciado não fala sobre criar uma tabela separada para telefone nem para endereço.

Comment: Exatamente, e você falou que deveria fazer, portanto está falando para fazer algo que o requisito não pede.

Comment: Sim o requesito não pede, mas a dúvida dele para validar os relacionamentos é valida a sugestão. Não existe motivo para criar relacionamentos desnecessários.

Comment: Não é válida porque o requisito é muito claro, poderia ser se o requisito não estive claro, então está mandando fazer algo que tornaria o modelo errado. E sua última frase contradiz todo o resto que disse. Se não existe motivo para criar relacionamentos desnecessários porque então manda criar relacionamentos desnecessários na sua resposta?

Comment: Mandei criar? Ou remover? Ou editar para dar sentido?

Comment: `alteraria a tabela de endereços, destrincharia ela em mais duas`

Comment: Bom é por isso que não existe só um DEV no mundo né. Pensou tudo só do meu jeito? Ou tudo só do seu jeito? Tragédia.

Comment: A dúvida é apenas sobre a lógica dos relacionamentos mesmo. Na tabela de telefone e endereço realmente fui além do que foi pedido no requisito, mas agradeço pela sugestão.

Comment: Trágico é em uma disciplina de exatas alguém achar que cada um pode fazer como bem entende e tudo está certo. O assunto é amplamente estudado e tem maneiras corretas de fazer de acordo com o requisito que está dado, só só aplicar os fundamentos desta disciplina.